# MySQL Retrieve Multiple Records For Each Record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, patients and insurances. Each patient can have several insurances, so I need to retrieve each patient and each of their insurances in separate rows so I can put them in a `JSON` array. For example:

```
{
    patient: John,
    address: apple,
    race: white
    insurances: // array of insurances for this patient
}
```

Will I have to retrieve each patient in PHP then use their ID to grab each insurance record? Is there a faster way of retrieving an array in MySQL for each group of rows belonging to each patient record? Thank you all.

**Patients**

```
-----+---------+------+------------
name | address | race | insuranceID
-----+---------+------+------------
john | apple   | white| 1
-----|---------|------+------------
mary | jane    | asian| 2
-----|---------|------+------------
sally| kay     | black| 3
```

**Insurances**

```
----+------+---------+------
 id | name | address | type
----+------+---------+------
  1 | edna | 112 n   | P
----+------|---------|------
  2 | maid | 45 st   | I
----+------|---------|------
  3 | mcare| 1235    | P
```

**NOTE**
*I am looking for implementation ideas, not fixing what I already have, I have nothing...*

Comment: how are your Patients and Insurance tables linked?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: You could use joins, at least that's what I think you're asking.

Comment: You would use mysql's [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: please show us what you've tried so far

Comment: I mentioned what I have tried, or the ways I think I can accomplish this, again "Will I have to retrieve each patient in PHP then use their ID to grab each insurance record?". See my edit for updated table.

Comment: Your updated table shows a one-to-one relationship. Are you designing these tables as you ask the question?

Comment: @DigitalChris no, they have a junction table in between that contains each patientID with their insuranceID. Still, that doesn't allow me to retrieve multiple rows for each record.

Comment: Edit: just saw your "NOTE". You can get all the info in a single query, using a "GROUP BY" clause.

Comment: @DigitalChris well, I just told you about the table. Will you help me find a solution?

Comment: @DigitalChris I don't see how this will retrieve each patient and all their insurance in one query, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target data structure seems to be a php array, let's call it `patients`, each element of which is itself an array describing the patient.

MySQL aside, you'd make this in php like so:

```
$patients = array();
/* for each patient */
  $patient = array();
  $patient[name]  = 'john';
  $patient[address] = '123 apple';
  $patient[race] = 'caucasian';
  /* for each payer for that patient */
    $insurance = array();
    $insurance[name] = 'edna';
    $insurance[type] = 'P';
    $patient[insurances[]] = $insurance;
  $patients[] = $patient;
/* now you can json encode the result */
$jpatient = json_encode($patients);
```

So the trick here is to get your MySQL result set to fit with `for each patient` and `for each payer` in this code.

You'll do that by issuing a query saying

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.address, p.race,
       i.id payerid, i.name payername, i.type payertype
  FROM patients p
  JOIN insurances i ON p.id = i.patient_id
 ORDER BY p.id, i.id
```

This will give you a resultset with one row for each payer. If a patient has more than one payer, the patient's data will be repeated (in consecutive rows). So, you'll need to detect, in your php code, when the patient id changes.

That looks something like this.  (I apologize, I don't have time to debug this.)

```
$patients = array();
$patient = false;
$previousid = -1;
while ( $row = $resultset->fetch_assoc() ) {
  if ( $row[id] != $previousid ) {
    /* this is a new patient */
    if ( !empty($patient) ) {
       /* we were already accumulating data for a patient */
       $patients[] = $patient;
       $patient = false;
       $previousid = $row[id];
    }
  }
  if ( empty ($patient) ) {
    /* we need to start a new patient data structure */
    $patient = array();
    $patient[name] = row[name];
    $patient[address] = row[address];
    $patient[race] = row[race];
  }
  $insurance = array();
  $insurance[name] = $row[payername];
  $insurance[type] = $row[payertype];
  $patient[insurances[]] = $insurance;
} /* end while fetch_assoc() */
if ( !empty($patient) ) {
  /* output last patient if any */
  $patients[] = $patient;
}
```

Comment: good solution the problem is, however, the huge amount of redundant data that will be retrieved.

Comment: Usually it's considered better practice to issue a single query and just deal with the duplicated data, than to issue nested queries.  It's certainly going to perform far better. Also, in data handling, we reserve the word *huge* to mean ten million rows or more.

Comment: @user3704920, with respect you're imagining a performance problem where there is none. Nested queries are far more expensive than duplicated data, especially considering that most patients will have less than a dozen or so associated insurances. It's not perfectly optimal, but that honestly doesn't matter in practice.

Comment: I understand, I guess this is a difficult solution and only so much can be done about performance. Thank you for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a many to many relationship between Patients and Insurances I would add one more table called Patient_Insurance and allow that to be a link table:

`---+------+
 Pid| Iid  | 
----+------+
  1 | 1    |
----+------|
  1 | 2    | 
----+------|
  2 | 1    |`

Then the quickest way I would imagine to achieve what you want would be to then populate your Patient array by selecting all from Patients, then iterate through that array and populate Insurances by looking for the user ID in Patient_Insurance and joining the Insurances data.

You're not going to get the results you want with just one query.

Comment: so if I have 100 patients I would be running 100 queries?

Comment: What? If there is a one-to-many relationship, you don't need a 3rd table, you just have a `PatientID` in the `insurances` table.   You are describing a valid setup for a many-to-many relationship. And you CAN get all the results in a single query.

Comment: You're right I did describe a many to many relationship, that was my mistake. Perhaps you could provide the query then?

Comment: @JoeyHinton if you see my question and note above you will see that what I require is help implementing this, I have nothing.

Comment: @user3704920 we can't write your code for you. You should understand enough to take the advice we've given you so far and run with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [SQLFiddle of what you want](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f5ba/2). Note that it is just a general approximation, I didn't include all the fields or set up primary keys, FKs etc.

The "many" table (insurance) needs a reference to the "one" table (Patient) which is `PatientID`:

```
create table Patient (id int, name varchar(20));
create table Insurance (id int, address varchar(100), PatientID int);
```

Then you can query like:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,
       i.id insuranceID, i.address
  FROM Patient p
  JOIN Insurance i ON p.id = i.PatientID
 ORDER BY p.id, i.id
```

And get:

```
ID  NAME    INSURANCEID     ADDRESS
1   bob     1               1 main st
1   bob     2               1 left st
1   bob     3               1 right st
3   joe     4               joe lives here
3   joe     5               joe other house
```

Comment: thanks, but again the problem lies in the amount of redundant data making this a very slow application. I guess I will have to use some other method.